# Need to pass long text variables from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Amateur here... I have an SQL query on an JS page and need to pass the variables onto a PHP webpage.  I know how to pass the more simple variables through the URL, but am struggling in finding and executing the most efficient way to passing a long string, i.e. the text description of a point

Here on the JS side, I have:

```
downloadUrl("php_genxml1.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var points = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("point");
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      var id = points[i].getAttribute("id");
      var name = points[i].getAttribute("name");
      var description = points[i].getAttribute("description");
      var url = "PHPWebPage.php?name=" + name + "&id=" + id;
```

To get the id from the URL, I have used stuff like the standard

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

I know I could re run a query based off that id from the URL, but that surely doesn't sound the most efficient. I know my options (array, sessions, etc) for whatever that's worth.

Thanks for any help, C

Comment: You want to pass a SQL query to the server? You should never never never do that. You would be given any user full access to the database.

Comment: You can send a longer description without any problems, just make sure you `encodeURIComponent()` the values. If it really gets too long (hard to imagine for a point description...), you can POST instead of GET. About the maximum length: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try POSTing the data instead.  It also makes it less likely for someone to just edit your URL in the browser to get data they're not supposed to have.

Comment: This. `GET` request sizes are usually limited to a few kilobytes, `POST` request limits are usually at least a few megabytes.